# How to fix in MVC core such error: Data Tables warning: table id=Data-Ajax error. http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve BEST SELLER items from my Product List.
I have mentioned below what I have done till now to make it work, and I think my error is in my controller where I couldn't accomplish the logic correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

By the way the error I am getting while trying to load my data table is:
Data Tables warning: table id=Data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7.

```
\\ in BestSellerProduct.js
       var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
loadDataTable();
});
$('\<div class="loading"\>Loading\</div\>').appendTo('body');
function loadDataTable() {
dataTable = $('#Data').DataTable({
"ajax": {
"url": "/Admin/BestSellerProducts/GetAll"
},
"columns": \[

            { "data": "title", "width": "15%" },
    
            { "data": "price", "width": "15%" },
    
            { "data": "category.name", "width": "15%" },
    
            { "data": "salescount", "width": "15%" },
    
            { "data": "imageurl", "width": "15%" },
                            
        ]
    });

}
function Validate Input(x) {
var i = x;
if (document.getElementById("salescount").value == "") {
Swal.fire({
icon: 'error',
title: i,
text: 'Please Upload an Image!',
});
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

```
\\ in my view page
     @model Product

\<h3\>Best Seller Products\</h3\>
      
    <table id="Data" asp-action="BestSellerCategory" class="table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
    
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>SalesCount</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                 </tr>
        </thead>
       
    </table>
@section Scripts{
\<script src="\~/js/BestSellerProducts.js"\>\</script\>
}
```

```
\\in my controller

    \[HttpPost\]
public IActionResult BestSellerCategory(Product para)
{
var data = \_unitOfWork.Product.GetAll(x =\> x.CategoryId == para.Id).ToList();
if (data != null)
{
for (int x = 0; x \< data.Count; x++)
{
data\[x\].SalesCount = para.Id;

                    _unitOfWork.Product.Update(data[x]);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                }
    
            }
            return RedirectToAction("BestSellerProducts", "Product");
    
        }
    
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult BestSellerCategory2(Product para)
        {
    
            return View();
    
        }
        public IActionResult BestSellerProducts()
        {
            ViewBag.Category = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll();
            ViewBag.Category2 = _unitOfWork.Category2.GetAll();
            return View();
        }
```

What I am looking for is to be filtered the "Best Seller Products" so I'll be able with it to build a carousel in the home page.

Thanks Indeed